Prove that $(X, d)$ is a complete metric space where $X$ is the set of all real sequences and $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by...
I am given a metric space $(X, d)$ where $X$ is the set of all real sequences and $d: X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ the metric defined by
$$
d(x, y) = \begin{cases}(\sup\{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_k = y_k \text{ for } k = 0, ..., n\})^{-1}: x_0 = y_0 \land x_1 = y_1\\ 1: x_0 \neq y_0 \lor x_1 \neq y_1\end{cases}.
$$
I need to show that $(X, d)$ is complete i.e. every Cauchy-sequence in $(X, d)$ converges. I am just really confused about this exercise since we are working with sequences of sequences and I do not have any intuition about what that is supposed to mean and the metric also seems really strange to me. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a hint on how to prove the statement.
What I have got so far
Let $(x_n) \subset (X, d)$ be Cauchy. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall n, m \geq N: d(x_n, x_m) < \epsilon$. I think we can ignore the case where $d(x, y) = 1$ since after some $N$ the sequences that are elements of $(x_n)$ must all satisfy $x_0 = y_0 \land x_1 = y_1$ because otherwise $(x_n)$ would not be Cauchy. So we can assume in the above inequality $d(x_n, x_m) = (\sup\{n \in \mathbb{N}: x_n^k = x_m^k \text{ for } k = 0, ..., n\})^{-1}$ where $x^k_n$ denotes the $k$-th term of the sequence that is $x_n$. And in order for that to get arbitrarily small the sequences that are elements of $(x_n)$ must become more and more "equal" to each other so the supremum gets large. But I do not know how this helps me in proving that $(x_n)$ converges.
